# How Can I Reset Graphics Drivers and Restore Defaults?

Tags: debian, crunchbang, amd, proprietary-drivers

I tried to install AMD graphics without reading. My CrunchBang crashed and now every time I try to login, my keyboard inputs don't go into the login screen. I can reset X with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and it resets but same issue appears. How can I fix that and any other driver issues that may have evolved from my ignorance?

Comment: What exact operating system? Exact versions? What drivers did you try to install, and how? Have you looked for instructions to uninstall the drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this solution is for debian, I don't know if it works for crunchbang, but I think it should.

It's a pretty easy thing. All you have to know is the date when the new version of drivers (or xorg) was added to the repository. You can check it here: http://packages.qa.debian.org/f/fglrx-driver.html

If you're updating your system regularly, you probably know what version caused the problems. If you don't know, you have to check the aptitude log, it's usually in /var/log/ directory. When you know the date, you just have to find a snapshot of the repository you have -- go to http://snapshot.debian.org/ and add a repository from that date. Let's say it's February 10th -- http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/?year=2014&month=2 . There's 4 of them:

```
2014-02-10 04:35:37
2014-02-10 10:06:43
2014-02-10 16:14:41
2014-02-10 22:04:02
```

Let's say you want this one: http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20140210T220402Z/

You have to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add the following:

```
deb     http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20140210T220402Z/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20140210T220402Z/ testing main contrib non-free
```

If you tried update your package list, you would get the error:

```
E: Release file for http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20140210T220402Z/dists/testing/InRelease is expired (invalid since 5d 16h 37min 17s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

So, you have to run `aptitude update` in this way:

```
aptitude -o 'Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false' update
```

Now, you have to add a rule to the `/etc/apt/preferences` file:

```
Package: *
Pin: origin snapshot.debian.org
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

And check it:

```
# apt-cache policy fglrx-driver
fglrx-driver:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:13.12-4
  Version table:
     1:14.1~beta1.3-1 0
        500 http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ testing/non-free amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ sid/non-free amd64 Packages
     1:13.12-4 0
       1001 http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20140210T220402Z/ testing/non-free amd64 Packages
```

If you see the snapshot repository with the pin 1001, you can downgrade the system to the date of the snapshot:

```
root:~# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dvdauthor libaacplus2 libav-tools libavfilter3 libboost-system1.53.0 libfreenect0.2 libgcrypt20 liblept4 libprocps3 libprotobuf8 libtsk10
  libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0 libxcb-xf86dri0 libxshmfence1 python-nbxmpp python3-pyqt4 python3-sip vcdimager
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cups-core-drivers cups-filters-core-drivers devede mencoder
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfreenect0.1 libgpod4-nogtk libimobiledevice4 liblastfm1 liblept3 libloudmouth1-0 libofa0 libplist1 libprocps0 libprotobuf7 libqjson0
  libtsk3-3 libusbmuxd2 python-qt4 python-sip usbmuxd xserver-xorg-video-qxl
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libprocps3
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  amarok amarok-common amarok-utils apt apt-utils autoconf binfmt-support bmon bootlogd busybox convertall cpp-4.8 cryptmount cups cups-client
  cups-common cups-daemon cups-filters cups-ppdc cups-server-common debootstrap deluge deluge-common deluge-gtk deluge-web deluged
  dictionaries-common dmsetup dos2unix file fonts-freefont-ttf g++-4.8 gajim gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-base geoip-database gnupg gnuplot-x11 gnutls-bin
  gpac gpac-modules-base gparted gpgv gpm graphviz initscripts intel-microcode iproute iproute2 iputils-ping iso-codes keepass2 krb5-locales
  liba52-0.7.4 libapache2-mod-php5 libapt-inst1.5 libapt-pkg4.12 libarchive13 libasan0 libatomic1 libavcodec54 libavdevice53 libavformat54
  libavresample1 libavutil52 libbluray1 libcaca0 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcdt4 libcgraph5 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsfilters1
  libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libcwidget3 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libdbus-glib-1-2 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdevmapper1.02.1
  libepub0 libfontembed1 libgcc-4.8-dev libgcc1 libgfortran3 libglib2.0-0 libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls26 libgnutls28 libgomp1 libgpac2
  libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port10 libgraph4 libgraphite2-3 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0
  libgudev-1.0-0 libgvc5 libgvpr1 libharfbuzz-icu0 libharfbuzz0b libio-socket-ssl-perl libisl10 libitm1 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0
  libltdl7 libmagic1 libmhash2 libmono-accessibility4.0-cil libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-corlib4.0-cil libmono-corlib4.5-cil
  libmono-data-tds4.0-cil libmono-i18n-cjk4.0-cil libmono-i18n-mideast4.0-cil libmono-i18n-other4.0-cil libmono-i18n-rare4.0-cil
  libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil libmono-i18n4.0-all libmono-i18n4.0-cil libmono-posix4.0-cil libmono-security4.0-cil libmono-sqlite4.0-cil
  libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libmono-system-core4.0-cil libmono-system-data4.0-cil libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil
  libmono-system-enterpriseservices4.0-cil libmono-system-runtime-serialization-formatters-soap4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil
  libmono-system-transactions4.0-cil libmono-system-web-applicationservices4.0-cil libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil libmono-system-web4.0-cil
  libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libmono-web4.0-cil libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil libmozjs24d
  libmp3lame0 libmysqlclient18 libnewt0.52 libnspr4 libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime libpam0g libpathplan4 libpcap0.8 libpci3
  libpcsclite1 libpipeline1 libportaudio2 libpython3-stdlib libpython3.3 libpython3.3-minimal libpython3.3-stdlib libquadmath0 libsasl2-2
  libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0 libstdc++-4.8-dev libstdc++6 libstfl0 libswscale2 libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-journal0
  libsystemd-login0 libtesseract3 libtool libtorrent-rasterbar7 libtsan0 libudev1 libwildmidi-config libwildmidi1 libxdot4 libzip2 linuxlogo
  live-build lvm2 lynx lynx-cur manpages minitube mono-4.0-gac mono-gac mono-runtime mpd mumble mysql-client mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 nmap nvidia-detect openssh-client openssh-server pciutils php-pear php5 php5-cgi php5-cli
  php5-common php5-curl php5-dev php5-gd php5-imap php5-intl php5-json php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-sqlite
  php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl procps psi-plus psi-plus-common psi-plus-l10n psi-plus-plugins psi-plus-skins psi-plus-sounds psmisc
  python-gtkspell python-imaging python-keyring python-libtorrent python-lxml python-markupsafe python-pil python-simplejson python3
  python3-keyring python3-minimal python3.3 python3.3-minimal qbittorrent qbittorrent-nox qnapi qpdfview qpdfview-djvu-plugin qpdfview-ps-plugin
  qtchooser reiser4progs sed shared-mime-info sleuthkit smartmontools sqlite3 ssh sudo sysv-rc sysvinit sysvinit-core sysvinit-utils tar
  tesseract-ocr texlive texlive-base texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-generic-recommended texlive-lang-polish texlive-latex-base
  texlive-latex-recommended texlive-pictures tmux udev udevil virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-guest-additions-iso virtualbox-qt whiptail
  x11-common xarchiver xbase-clients xclip xorg xserver-common xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse xserver-xorg-video-all
  xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-mach64
  xserver-xorg-video-mga xserver-xorg-video-modesetting xserver-xorg-video-neomagic xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
  xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-savage xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sisusb
  xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware xtables-addons-common xtables-addons-dkms
  xulrunner-24.0 zenmap
1 upgraded, 17 newly installed, 326 downgraded, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 273 MB/296 MB of archives.
After this operation, 12.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

You can play with the package list in the `/etc/apt/preferences` file. Instead of `Package: *`, you can set something like `Package: *fglrx*`, you have to figure this out, but you have to pay attention to Xorg -- it's packages also should be downgraded.

Comment: I don't understand. I reinstalled Crunchbang over the old partition I had.